# Trying to set bottom shadow transparent in triangles

Tags: html, css, sass

I have 2 pens. The first is not responsive, then I figured out that there is another version, and that is responsive.

[Not responsive pen](https://codepen.io/snhasani/pen/FoeBK)

```
                @import "compass/css3";

            $dark-blue: #013870;

            @mixin moz-border-colors($color: none) {
              -moz-border-bottom-colors: $color;
              -moz-border-left-colors: $color;
              -moz-border-right-colors: $color;
              -moz-border-top-colors: $color;
            }

            @mixin triangle($color, $order) {
              @extend .triangle;
              border-top-color: $color;
              top: $order * -60px;
              z-index: $order + 1;
            }

            .triangle {
              border-right-color: transparent;
              border-bottom-color: transparent;
              border-left-color: transparent;
              border-style: solid;
              border-width: 600px 600px 0;
              content: "";
              height: 0;
              position: absolute;
              top: 0;
              left: 0;
              width: 0;
              @include moz-border-colors();
              @include filter(drop-shadow(-12px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)));
            }

            .triangle--1 {
                @include triangle(lighten($dark-blue, 10%), 1);
            }

            .triangle--2 {
                @include triangle(lighten($dark-blue, 15%), 2);
            }

            .triangle--3 {
                @include triangle(lighten($dark-blue, 20%), 3);
            }

            .triangle--4 {
                @include triangle(lighten($dark-blue, 25%), 4);
            }

            .triangle--5 {
              @include triangle(lighten($dark-blue, 30%), 5);
                    }
```

[Responsive pen](https://codepen.io/snhasani/pen/dztbG)

```
                @import "compass/css3";

            $dark-blue: #013870;

            @mixin moz-border-colors($color: none) {
              -moz-border-bottom-colors: $color;
              -moz-border-left-colors: $color;
              -moz-border-right-colors: $color;
              -moz-border-top-colors: $color;
            }

            @mixin triangle-padding-top($color, $order) {
              @extend .triangle;
              border-top-color: $color;
              padding-top: 50% - ($order * 5%);
              z-index: $order + 1;
            }

            .triangle--down {
                width: 100%;
                height: 0;
                padding-left:50%;
                position: absolute;
                overflow: hidden;

                &:after {
                  border-style: solid;
                  border-color: transparent;
                  border-width: 100rem 100rem 0;
                  content: "";
                  display: block;
                  height: 0;
                  margin-left:-100rem;
                  margin-top:-100rem;
                  width: 0;
                  @include moz-border-colors();
                  @include filter(drop-shadow(-12px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4)));
                }
            }

            .triangle--down__0 {
              @extend .triangle--down;
              @include triangle-padding-top(0);

              &:after {
                border-top-color: $dark-blue;
              }
            }

            .triangle--down__1 {
              @extend .triangle--down;
              @include triangle-padding-top(1);

              &:after {
                border-top-color: lighten($dark-blue, 5%);
              }
            }

            .triangle--down__2 {
              @extend .triangle--down;
              @include triangle-padding-top(2);

              &:after {
                border-top-color: lighten($dark-blue, 10%);
              }
            }

            .triangle--down__3 {
              @extend .triangle--down;
              @include triangle-padding-top(3);

              &:after {
                border-top-color: lighten($dark-blue, 15%);
              }
            }
            .triangle--down__4 {
              @extend .triangle--down;
              @include triangle-padding-top(4);

              &:after {
                border-top-color: lighten($dark-blue, 20%);
              }
            }
```

The problem, and I tried very hard to fix it from myself, is the bottom shadow in each triangle, in the responsive version it appears to shadow line in bottom and I can not hide or remove it.

Very thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this seemed to work for me remove `overflow: hidden;` from `.triangle--down` and change it to `overflow: inherit;`

```
.triangle--down {
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    padding-left:50%;
    position: absolute;
    overflow: inherit;
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: This works for the tips of the triangles but then the div goes off the screen.
But the way, overflow: none does not seem to be a valid attribute, maybe it would have worked erasing that line but it does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Rodrigo i just updated the post, inherit works and is a valid attribute but not too sure what you mean by "but then the div goes off the screen"

Comment: Thanks for the help, i resolved it changing the position attribute of the main div and clearing the others attempts